# Como usar um tema no wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou tentando usar um pacote de  temas do WPF, mas não consigo chamar ele, quando eu do o using diz que falta a referencia e eu nao consigo encontrar nenhum tutorial nem nada atual sobre isso.

[image: erro]

tentei instalar usando o nuget e os temas desse link

http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes

OBS: Estou usando o VS12 e VS13

Comment: Verificou se o WPF não está apontando o Client Profile invés de apontar pro seu .NET Framework? Por exemplo, se a sua biblioteca aponta pro .NET 3.5, tenha certeza que o WPF  também está apontando  o .NET 3.5 ou 4.0, não o Client Profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sei que a pergunta é antiga mas pode ajudar outros, eu conheço duas formas de fazer:

1º Forma é Via Nuget: Click com o botão direito sobre o projeto e selecione a opção "Manage NuGet Packages" e instale o WPFThemes.

[image: Imagem 01]

Ele vai aicionar a referencia WPF.Themes automaticamente

[image: Imagem 02]

Agora em seu form principal faça igual a imagem abaixo

[image: Imagem 03]

Note que o dessa forma o tema só sera aplicado quando o projeto estiver em execução

[image: Imagem 04]

[image: Imagem 05]

2º Forma: Baixando o código do thema no link: https://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Adicione o arquivo do thema que você fez o download em seu projeto e dentro do app.xaml adicione a referência a ele:

[image: Imagem 06]

Note que dessa forma ele é carregado em modo design e você tem acesso ao código para editar conforme sua preferência.

Obj: Caso ele não apareça de primeira, de um rebuild em sua solução, feche e abra o visual studio.

[image: Imagem 07]